# RSS Viewer in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

i have added a rss viewer wp in 2010.
But i m getting the error : The requested RSS feed could not be displayed. Please verify the settings and url for this feed. If this problem persists, please contact your administrator.
Please help , i m using NTLM Authentication and i am trying to use external site.

Answer (score 2):

First of all are you trying to retrieve RSS for an SharePoint list and have multiple servers? If so you might need to implement Kerberos to get it to work.

You will most definatley see more information in the SharePoint ULS logs: {SharePoint Root}/LOGS.

If you are using web proxies you might need to bypass it.

Comment: i am trying to run an external rss feed . So i guess the prob is with the web proxies ?

Comment: Can you share me sme info on how to do this ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wael/archive/2007/07/01/enable-proxy-settings-in-sharepoint-web-config-to-view-rss-viewer-web-part.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Double check the List Settings and see if RSS is enabled for that particular List.  I think by default it is.  I was peeking at Central Admin to see if we can control RSS at a web app level and didn't see anything but you might want to poke around there.